# Search/Navigate LDAP for couple of million users

Tags: java, performance, ldap, ldap-query

We have LDAP(Directory Server) installed with couple of million users. When a new user selects the username, we need to validate the username in LDAP and it takes more than minute and half which is very slow. Also when we create a new user, it happens the same time. I have written the code in java and it worked fine with 5-10,000 users. So any ideas on improving the search time would help.

The issue is all the users are in the same tree - no groups or orgs, this is the requirement and we cannot change it. I tried in the commandline using ldapsearch and I got the result back instantly. I used

```
"ldapsearch -D "" -w "" -h  -p  -b "ou=company,dc=abc,dc=com" uid=user1"
```

The code is below:

```
public String userCheck(String name){
        String text = "";


        Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xxxxxxxxxx:1389");
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, ""); ////////these values are all defined
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "" ); 
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "");
        try
        {
            //DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(environment);

            String searchBase = "ou=company,dc=abc,dc=com"; ////////////////////////This is where all the 2 million users are stored
            String FILTER = "(uid="+name+")";
            SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
            ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = context.search(searchBase, FILTER, ctls);
            SearchResult result = answer.next();
            javax.naming.directory.Attribute email = result.getAttributes().get("mail");
            javax.naming.directory.Attribute cn = result.getAttributes().get("cn");
            text = "Taken" ;
            context.close();
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            text = "available" ;

        }

        return text;

    }
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I was able to get it faster. I recreated the indexes and regenerated them and it works fine now. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You're doing this wrong anyway. It isn't any use searching the directory to see if a UID is taken before creating a user. That can change immediately afterwards. You should just try to insert the user and deal with the failure if the UID is already taken. And if you allocate UIDs correctly in the first place, i .e. via the UUID class, they will never be already taken.

Comment: Not saying that @EJP is wrong about inserting and then dealing wiht failure, but the search should return in a few milliseconds. Is uid indexed?  

Not sure how the UUID class can be used to generate "proper" uid values though. EJP, can you explain?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The LDAP user is created with another app user in sync, so we cannot insert first and check, we need to check if the user is present first. Moreover even for inserting it takes the same time.

Comment: I have not done any indexing for uid. I will check on how to index the LDAP columns. Thanks. But as I mentioned, when I run the ldapsearch via command line, it returned the result fast. But I will still try indexing and check. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the ldap has additional indexes and uid is one of the additional index and it was there by default. So I am not sure what else I can add. Thanks.